# Commutator $[E^m, F^n]$ in $U_q(sl2)$

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

How do I compute $[E^m, F^n]$ in $U_q(sl2)$, which is generated by $E,F,K$ with $K$ invertible such that
\begin{align}
    KEK^{-1}=q^2E,\quad KFK^{-1}=q^{-2}F, [E,F] = \frac{K - K^{-1}}{q - q^{-1}}
\end{align}
for $q\neq \pm1$ a nonzero number?

I am too dense. I arrive at
\begin{align}
    [E^m, F^n] = \sum_{i=0}^{m-1} E^{(m-1)-i} [E,F^n]E^i,
\end{align}
where the explicit form of $[E,F^n]$ is known. 
But then I don't see how to proceed...

---

**Edit 1:** In particular, I want the commutator to be expressed in the PBW-basis ordered like $K^i E^j F^k$.

---

**Edit 2:**
Actually, after thinking about the comments by used @joppy, I realized the following simplification.
I do *not* care about the full expression. I want:
\begin{align}
\text{terms in } [E^m, F^m] \text{ supported on } \{K^i E^m F^m | i\in \mathbb{N} \}
\end{align}

Comment: What kind of form do you want the answer to have? Are you trying to apply this commutator to a highest-weight vector or something?

Comment: @Joppy Elementary. Without commutators and preferably in the PBW basis $K^i E^ j F^k$, I should have said that. Will change question once I get home. I don't know how applying it to highest weight vector helps here?

Comment: You can look around for formulas for "commutator of powers", but I'm not sure that knowing a different form for this commutator will be helpful unless you had something specific in mind. Usually its just a giant difficult-to-use sum...

Comment: Thanks, I realized what I need. And just to add: I did not find a formula for it in any of the standard text books on quantum groups.

Answer (score 1):

Whoops. Thanks to user @Joppy I realized that I did not think carefully about what I wanted.
I will not tell you why, but I do not need the full commutator; rather only
\begin{align}
     \text{terms in } [E^m, F^m] \text{ supported on } 
     \{K^i E^m F^m | i\in \mathbb{N} \} \ .
\end{align}
But there is no such term, since the number of $E$'s + the number of $F$'s in each term is less than $2m$. This is seen either by the formula with the sum I provided, or just by thinking a bit about $[E,F]$.

Thus, the answer is:
\begin{equation}
    E^m F^m = F^m E^m + \text{other terms I don't care about}
\end{equation}